# How do you code three summation functions in WinBUGS?

Tags: bugs

I recently learned how to use winbugs. I know nothing about coding and programming. My model is not included in the set of distributions that are already available in winbugs.

This is a trivariate poisson model with covariance structure:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HS4u7.png]

There is this `dloglike` function in winbugs to create a custom model. You just need to get the log transformation and you're good to go. Getting the log transformation is the easy part. What makes me crazy is the presence of those three summation functions. I don't know how to convert them into the Bugs language. I would like to show you my Winbugs code but it is kind of messy. Can you please help me?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ansel. Since this is a question on a computing environment, should we move it to SO?

Comment: Hey @StasK, I'm sorry but what is SO?

Comment: SO stands for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), which is Stack Exchange's Q & A site for programming questions, whereas Cross Validated is for statistics questions.

Comment: Thanks again @gung for editing my post. In the future I will try my best to be more objective when expressing my question.